# How to add user command to vi/vim to have multiple conditions to search the content?

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

Our servers only have vi/vim to check the log files and I feel searching in vi is painful and limited.
I wonder if it's possible to provide an executable file in the path and then use the `vi` user command to call it and the user command is able to accept multiple conditions like `A=value1 && B=value2`, `A=value1 || B=value2`, etc and then it searches the content in the open `vi` editor and places the cursor in matching text.

If it's possible please describe a bit the steps.

Comment: Using the basic regex syntax with vim's native search command can cover most of the searching tasks. How complex will your *conditions* be?

Comment: Since the vim search allows regular expressions, every regular language can be processed/searched. It is highly unlikely to have a condition, that can't be searched with vim, but can be searched with another generic search. Such a condition most likely will require a specific interpreter (a.k.a. a script with memory). So you will have more success asking us here, if you provide an exact example

Answer (score 1):

If what you have on your machines is *actually* Vim, you should be able to leverage the "quickfix" feature. In a nutshell, you can:

- feed a list of locations to Vim,
- optionally tell Vim how to parse that list,
- go through that list with commands like `:cnext` or `:lprevious`,
- display that list in a special window,
- batch operate on every line in the list.

In the simplest scenario, your hypothetical external program would output a list formatted in a way Vim already understand, like:

```
filename.txt:3067:12:some text
filename.txt:4321:7:some text
```

which could be fed "directly" to Vim:

```
$ vim -q <(yourcommand)

# also open the quickfix window
$ vim -q <(yourcommand) +cwindow
```

or via some file:

```
$ vim -q yourfile
```

It can all be done from within Vim by telling it to use your program instead of `grep` for the `:grep` command:

```
set grepprg=yourcommand
```

and doing:

```
:grep <your arguments>
```

References:

```
:help quickfix
:help :cnext
:help :lprevious
:help -q
:help -+c
:help :cwindow
:help :grep
:help 'grepprg'
:help 'grepformat'
```